# How to merge rows in dictionary python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, group-by

i have a dataframe like that

```
MV id   NAME   ADDRESS  DOC  DOCTYPE PHONE
1  100  Mark   Home     299  NI      {123,456}
2  100  John   Work     A123 Pass    {789,101}
3  100         Club
```

what i want to do is to merge the columns that has the same id into one cell in dictionary like this and make the key of a value in dictionary from another column

```
id   NAME              ADDRESS                          DOC                    PHONE
100  {1:Mark,2:John}   {1:'Home',2:'Work',3:'Club'}     {NI:'299',Pass:'A123'} {1:{123,456},2:{789,101}}
```

as u can see i used 2 columns as a key column `mv` used as a key in `(Name,Address,Phone)`
and i used column `DOCTYPE` as key in `DOC` so how can i do something like that i tried this

```
agg={'id':'first','NAME':dict,'ADDRESS':dict,'PHONE':dict}
    df_new=df.groupby(['CUSTOMER_CODE'],as_index=False).aggregate(agg)
    return df_new
```

but it gave me this output

```
id   Name             Address                 Phone
100  {0:Mark,1:John}  {0:Home,1:Work,2:Club}  {0:{123,456},1:{789,101}}
```

Comment: Please provide your input [as code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464), the current format is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your empty cells are NaN, you can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

Let's first see how we could aggregate with a single reference:

```
df.set_index('MV').groupby('id', as_index=False).agg(lambda s: s.dropna().to_dict())
```

Output:

```
    id                    NAME                            ADDRESS                    DOC               DOCTYPE                             PHONE
0  100  {1: 'Mark', 2: 'John'}  {1: 'Home', 2: 'Work', 3: 'Club'}  {1: '299', 2: 'A123'}  {1: 'NI', 2: 'Pass'}  {1: '{123,456}', 2: '{789,101}'}
```

##### generic answer for different references

Now we can adapt that to use different reference columns:

```
def f(s):
    return s.dropna().to_dict()

d = {'MV': ['NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE'],
     'DOCTYPE': ['DOC']
    }

out = (pd.concat([df.set_index(k).groupby('id')[v].agg(f)
                 for k, v in d.items()], axis=1)
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
    id                    NAME                            ADDRESS                             PHONE                            DOC
0  100  {1: 'Mark', 2: 'John'}  {1: 'Home', 2: 'Work', 3: 'Club'}  {1: '{123,456}', 2: '{789,101}'}  {'NI': '299', 'Pass': 'A123'}
```

Comment: You're welcome @Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom lambda function with remove `NaN` or `None` in dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'MV': ['NAME','ADDRESS','PHONE'],
     'DOCTYPE':['DOC']}

d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}
print (d1)
{'NAME': 'MV', 'ADDRESS': 'MV', 'PHONE': 'MV', 'DOC': 'DOCTYPE'}

f = lambda x: {k: v for k, v in dict(zip(df.loc[x.index, d1[x.name]], x)).items() 
               if pd.notna(k) and pd.notna(v)}

out = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)[list(d1.keys())].agg(f)
print (out)
    id                    NAME                            ADDRESS  \
0  100  {1: 'Mark', 2: 'John'}  {1: 'Home', 2: 'Work', 3: 'Club'}   

                              PHONE                            DOC  
0  {1: '{123,456}', 2: '{789,101}'}  {'NI': '299', 'Pass': 'A123'}
```